# Issue with AzureAD Authentication in iOS app

Tags: swift, azure-ad-msal, iso, azure-authentication

We have created a app that uses Azure AD authentication and now facing issue with acquiring refresh token using MSAL library.
The issue that when ever authentication token expires(I believe expiry time is 1hr), I get HTTP status code 200 with HTML response which is Microsoft's login page.

I believe we should be getting 400 or 401 when token expires but somehow we are getting 200 with HTML response.
We have also used AcquireTokenSilent() method suggested in following guide but nothing changes.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=macOS

Microsoft authenticator allowing user to login.

Does anyone have any idea on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

400 code means bad request and 401 means Unauthorized. In case of token expire you should get 401 ( Unauthorized ). MSAL doesn't actually issue tokens or decide a token expiration, but rather ingests an acquires token from the Azure AD STS. MSAL will automatically refresh your access token after expiration when calling AcquireTokenSilentAsync. You're likely not getting automatic silent refreshes due to some kind of token cache miss. It's hard to say the specific issue without seeing your code

In your backend you can first check if the user is authenticated if it is then return the response. If not, then instead of executing the method you should return 401 (Unauthorized).

Comment: Actually we are not using API to verify token, token is verified at Gateway(Infra) level. So if  token is invalid request is not sent to API server.